# Warning: Cannot connect to database (connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 is not supported) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

While I was coding yesterday, suddenly the following error message came up:

***Warning:*** PDO::__construct(): Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 is not supported. Server is 3.23.58-log in /classes/DB.php on line 18
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported

Line 18 of my DB.php:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').
    ';dbname='.config::get('mysql/db'), 
    config::get('mysql/username'), 
    config::get('mysql/password')
);
```

So basically - if I got it right - the warning is saying that my mysql database is outdated. Doesn't make sense at all as it worked with PDO before and I didn't change anything in DB.php or Init.php.

- **Server Version:** 4.1.22-log
- **MySQL-Client-Version:** 5.1.61
- **phpMyAdmin:** 2.11.11.3
- **php-Version:** 5.6.12

Also, I've checked in domainfactory and there it clearly says my php Version is 5.6.12 and my MySQL Version is 5.1.16

So I feel like there is something wrong with my webhoster but I decided to ask here at first. Anything wrong with my settings?

Comment: So which is your mysql server version after all? 4.1.22-log or 5.1.16?

Comment: Is there any reason to not upgrade your MySQL server? The version you are running is very old and has a ton of vulnerabilities in it.

Comment: I am not 100% sure @YourCommonSense I copied this from my phpmyadmin dashboard. But I believe it says 5.1.61 in domainfactory.

Comment: It's not my server, so I cannot update it by myself. I am pretty sure they've chosen the latest version available at domainfactory though. @Chris

Comment: Wow, if the latest version available at Domainfactory is 10 years old and unsupported that's pretty embarrassing. If it's the 13 year old version that the error message claims then that's even worse. Where did you get the MySQL server version you've posted from?

Comment: I copypasted the version from phpmyadmin dashboard. I will give them a quick call, I guess something went wrong on their side. @Chris

Comment: Yeah, it sounds very odd. It's almost like the server you are connecting to with PHP is not the same one that PHPMyAdmin is connecting to. I'm sure they will know more about what might be happening because they will know of any changes they made recently.

Comment: I'm myself hosted at domainFactory and they offer me three different MySQL versions, depending on which hostname I connect to: MySQL **3.23.58** (host `mysql.<mydomain>`); **4.1.22** (host `mysql4.<mydomain>`) and **5.6.19** (host `mysql5.<mydomain>`). I got that from the customer's web interface (not sure about its name in English, it's _"Kundenmenue"_ in Germany). Are you sure you have MySQL 5.1? Perhaps you are just using the wrong hostname.

Comment: I called them and they said they gonna fix it and so they did. They didn't tell me what exactly went wrong but I guess it had something to do with the short downtime on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that an too old MySql version is used.

Often **DomainFactory** users face the error, **when trying to connect to 127.0.0.1**

In case you are using Domainfactory **make sure to connect to "mysql5.[yourdomain].[yourtld]"**.